# How to make the webserver within Visual Studio serve content that’s viewable by other machines on the network?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I make the webserver within Visual Studio serve content that’s viewable by other machines on the network?

For example: When I press F5 and I give the other person the ip + port he/she can see the content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup Visual studio in order to use IIS to debug. Its in the properties.
If you do that then people can visit your debug.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-7/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's not possible.

From MS Site:

> If you cannot or do not want to use IIS as your Web server, you can still test your ASP.NET pages by using the ASP.NET Development Server. The ASP.NET Development Server, which is included with Visual Web Developer, is a Web server that runs locally on Windows operating systems, including Windows XP Home Edition. It is specifically built to serve, or run, ASP.NET Web pages under the local host scenario (browsing from the same computer as the Web server). In other words, the ASP.NET Development Server will serve pages to browser requests on the local computer. **It will not serve pages to another computer.** Additionally, it will not serve files that are outside of the application scope. The ASP.NET Development Server provides an efficient way to test pages locally before you publish the pages to a production server running IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You could installl IIS or IIS express and publish to them, otherwise as Franky says its not possible with Cassini (the VS inbuilt one)